# Magento query language in a cms page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, translation, block

I want to display a text only for a specific language in a cms page which contains a placeholder. So I cannot use the way with the translate.csv. (see http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento_how_add_translation_ability_into_cms_page_or_static_block.html) It would just display the placeholder in plane text. And since it's a CMS-Page from an plugin I can't change to a specific store view.

Is it possible to do an if query in the cms page like displayed below? (Or sort of) It should work in the cms page without the need to use or editing a phtml template.

```
if (store view = norsk) 
{
  <p>bla...</p>
  {{some placeholder}}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CMS block with a different version for each store view, and include it in your CMS page with `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is displaying the block only for Norwegian. So far so good. But I have that problem, that my Placeholder is not rendered - I just see it in plain text. I am using a PDF Invoice plugin and want to show the total amount of that order in the text only for Norwegian. Is there a Magento way to get total amount of the order maybe? (In that block then)

Comment: What's your placeholder ? And you're using a plugin that renders a CMS page to a PDF file ?

Comment: It's this plugin: http://www.magazento.com/english/magento-ext/magazento-extensions/pdf-invoice-shipment-credit-memo 

And afaik it's indeed rendering from a CMS Page. What I want to display is {{pdf.invoice.base_grand_total}}. (This is a placeholder coming from that plugin) It's working if I put it in the (Plugin) CMS page itself but not when the placeholder is in the block which I need because I need this info only for Norwegian. ;)

Comment: Ok, I better understand your problematic, and indeed a CMS block can't do the trick. From what's in the documentation, you could use `{{pdf.invoice.store_id}}` to get the store ID, but currently there is no actual `if` conditions for templates in base Magento (`if` and `depend` evaluate a single variable). It would require some custom development to make more complex conditional structures, you can check here for an example : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21534/. Or maybe the extension developers could consider adding this feature

Answer (score 1):

I made an extension with this topic, feel free to use it or modify it!

https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_Translate